# Is pulling a Gem from its Git repo crazy for an App in production?

Tags: rubygems, bundler

I recently took over an application, and one of its gems its being installed directly from the repo, of course it works in production now because when it was launched everything worked just fine, however, on my local there is a bunch of broken stuff because I'm pulling from the git repo's head.

My question, are there any best practices/patterns this application is violating by using the gem directly from the repo and then just existing like this in production mode? I think it is nuts, but I can't find any good practices for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `bundle install`, the exact commit hash used is inserted into `Gemfile.lock`. If `Gemfile.lock` is committed to the git repo for the app, then you should always be running from the same commit wherever you run `bundle install`, regardless of what has changed in the upstream repo. This should make it pretty safe to do.

If you're getting the git repo's head, then that suggests that `Gemfile.lock` is not in source control. It is definitely recommended to commit that file: it is how Bundler ensures that the same versions of gems are installed on different machines. See http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/commit-it-or-else/

That said, a lot of teams prefer to build artifacts that include all of the gem dependencies before deploying. This means you don't need to hit any external sites to deploy (other than where you're hosting the artifacts).

### Before Deployment

1. On a build server (e.g., using a continuous integration app), clone your app's git repo.
2. Run `bundle package --all`. This copies all of the gem files and git gem repos into `./vendor/cache`.
3. Run whatever tests you need to validate that the artifact is good.
4. `tar` up the whole directory (excluding `.git`) and upload it to a file server. It's a good idea to put some combination of timestamp, version number, incrementing build number, and git commit hash in the filename.

### During Deployment

1. Download the desired artifact tarball onto the app server.
2. Unpack it into a directory.
3. `cd` to the unpacked directory.
4. Run `bundle install --deployment`. This installs the gems from `vendor/cache` and does not need to hit the network.

Note that this works best if the build server is running the same OS as the production server. Some gems have platform-specific variants `bundle package` will download the gem file for the platform it is run on.